# seedling time; does it meet the requirement of terminology?

Tags: terminology

The plants were harvested at 28th day of seedling time.

seedling time - does it meet the requirement of terminology?

Comment: By "meet the requirement of terminology" do you mean "do people use this phrase?"

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Yes, is it common?

Comment: What specific crop are you writing about?

Comment: This really isn't a language question, but word usage in a technical context. You might ask it on [***Gardening & Landscaping SE***](http://gardening.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @StoneyB: It was Amaranth (lat. _Amaranthus hibridus_)

Comment: Ah. I thought I might be able to track down some more technical terminology, but *A.hybridus* is regarded as a weed in US agriculture!

Comment: Here's language from a [publication](http://www.nda.agric.za/docs/Brochures/Amaranthus.pdf) of the South African Dept. of Agricullture, Forests and Fisheries: "Most amaranth cultivars grow rapidly and may be harvested from 30 to 55
days from sowing, when they reach a height of 0,6 m. "

Answer (score 1):

The agronomists I have worked with usually count the time from harvest in days after planting or sowing. That event is sometimes called "seeding", without the "l".

"Seedling" is something different: it is ordinarily the name for the plant at a very early stage of its actual growth, usually as it emerges from the ground, before it has developed frank leaves. Agronomists usually call the stage (as opposed to the plant itself) "emergence".

So depending on which event you want to count from, you should speak of the 28th day after planting or after emergence.

ADDED:
If your "seedling time" means the time at which seedlings propagated in trays are replanted in the field where they will grow to maturity, we speak of this as "transplanting". The [Connecticut Agricultural Experimentation Station](http://www.ct.gov/caes/lib/caes/documents/publications/fact_sheets/forestry_and_horticulture/how_to_grow_vegetable_amaranth_in_connecticut.pdf) writes that "Vegetable amaranth is ready to harvest about a month after transplanting."

Comment: I believe it is not seeding time @StoneyB